# Prevent unauthorized access to a webpage using jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say, a link to a person is sent to a user via email. If the person is already logged into the webpage in his/her browser, clicking on the link takes him/her to the page. However, if he/she is not logged in, he/she should be asked to login in order to access the page. Is there a way to achieve the above functionality using jquery, javascript?

Comment: If you want any level of actual security, you would need to control this from the server side. How would is your login state currently persisted?

Comment: Assuming the authorization is handled at the server level, you could use something like jQuery-UI's modal dialog and prompt for a password (server renders code when user's not logged in) or you redirect them to a login page with some "returnUrl" parameter.

Comment: How are you currently managing sessions ? If you're using cookies you might want to check them using Javascript, if you're using $_SESSION parameters or any method using PHP, there's no other choice than using PHP to check if the user is currently logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Build a back-end authentication system, using AJAX and whatever your server-side language is.

From there, develop a hypermedia-style of content-system, and a modular, "widget"-based application delivery model.

Within your hypermedia responses to login (plus passing whatever relevant path information was gained from the e-mail), either redirect the page to a new page (based on the linked response from the server), or download the widgets requested from the server (for whatever application you're displaying media in), and then stream in AJAX content (again, from a URL dictated by the server-response).

This is about as close as you're going to get to security, in terms of delivering things to the client, in real-time, with authentication.

If you were to load the reports/gallery/game/whatever, and put a div over it, and ask for users to log in, then smart users can just kill the div.

If you include the content, or include the application components (JS files), or even include the links to the JS files which will request and display the content, then clever people are again going to disassemble that, in 20 seconds, flat.

The only way I can see to do this is to have a common request-point, to touch the server, and conditionally load your application, based on "next-steps" URLs, passed to the client, based on successful authorization and/or successfully completing whatever the previous step was, plus doing authentication of some form on each request (REST-based tokens+nonces, or otherwise)...

This would keep the content (and any application-structure which might have vulnerabilities) from the client, until you can guarantee that the client has been properly authorized, and the entire application is running inside of multiple enclosed/sandboxed modules, with no direct access to one another, and only instance-based access to a shared-library.

Is it worth the work?
Who knows.

Are we talking about a NORAD nuclear-launch iPhone app, which must run in JavaScript?
Then no, engineering this whole thing for the next six months isn't overboard.

And again, all of this security falls over as soon as one person leaves themselves logged-in, and leaves their phone on the table (biometric authentication as well, then?).

Are we talking about a gallery or discount-offers that you want to prevent people to log into, so you know that only the invited people are using them?
Well, then an 18-month project to engineer, develop, debug and deploy a system like this is probably going to be overkill.

In this case, perhaps you can just do your best to prevent the average person from stealing your content or using your cut-prices, and accept that people who take the time to dig into and reverse-engineer everything are going to find a way to get what they want, 95 times out of 100.

In that case, perhaps just putting a login div overtop of the page IS what you're going to be looking for...

If you're dealing with, say a company back-end, or with company fiscals or end-user, private-data, or anything of the sort, then aside from meeting legal requirements for collection/display/storage, how much extra work you put into the security of the system depends on how much your company's willing to pay to do it.

If it makes you feel better, there are companies out there that pay $60,000-$150,000 a year, to use JS tracking/testing programs from Adobe. Those programs sit right there, on the webpage, most of the time, for anybody to see, as long as you know where to look.

So this isn't exactly an unknown problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. By authenticating (login) you can store a "loggedIn" cookie which you have to delete by session end (logout or closing the browser). You can use that cookie to check if somebody is logged in or not. If not logged in, than you can display the login page and send the login request with ajax. Btw it is not a good practice to use hybrid applications like that. It is better to use SPA-s with REST service, or implement this on server side.